# Memoization of built in function

Tags: memoization

What is the best way to let mathematica memoize built-in function like e.g.

```
SphericalHarmonicY[l,m,th,ph]
```

One possibility would be for sure:

```
 sphericalHarmonicY[l_,m_,th_,ph_]:= sphericalHarmonicY[l,m,th,ph]=SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, th, ph]
```

But is there some function that works like:

```
 Memoize[SphericalHarmonicY]
```

And I can still use the original definition and Mathematica will store the values in the memory and access already calculated values later on?

Comment: Try looking up `Once`. Just make sure the values you want to memoize get `With`ed into the `Once` (otherwise it will just remember `SphericalHarmonicY[l,m,th,ph]` symbolically rather than any particular numeric value for it).

Comment: I assume this question is mainly about improving performance, and `Once` hardly seems efficient to me.  The speed-up is about half what you get with memoization (based on repeated evaluation at many different points), the initial overhead is significant, and it's not really easier to code....